# Smooth streaming + Playready together on Windows 8 application

Tags: windows-8, drm, smooth-streaming, playready

I am trying my hands on Windows 8 Application development and was trying for Playready and Smooth streaming. There are sample applications available which explain on how to implement smooth streaming and playready individually.

But I am not able to find a way on how to implement smooth streaming and playready together.
Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way on how to do it, you need to make few changes to sample application provided for Playready ( found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-PlayReady-sample-5c1aefaf) )

1. Install smooth streaming and playready ADK.
2. Add reference for smooth streaming in your playready sample application and change the platform target to x64 for the project.
3. Modify the MEDIA to use some manifest url for eg. : http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1PR/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest
   and modify LAURL to use a valid license url for eg : http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx?PlayRight=1&UseSimpleNonPersistentLicense=1
4. In PLayback.cs -> public void Play(MediaElement mediaElement, string strMediaPath)
   add following lines,

   extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "text/xml");

   extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml");

It worked fine for me.